what is meant by rigidity in holomorphic dynamics?
When people talk about "rigidity" results in holomorphic dynamics, what kind of results do we consider as "rigidity" results?
For example, we often heard Thurston's rigidity theorem and there are many results in complex dynamics considered as rigidity.
If anyone can briefly explain the term "rigidity" would be appreciate!

Very broadly speaking, rigidity in the context of complex dynamics means a result of the type "Let $f$ be a holomorphic map satisfying such and such conditions. Assume that it is conjugated to another holomorphic map $g$ by a homeomorphism (sometimes you also ask for quasiconformality). Then $f$ and $g$ are conjugated by a holomorphic automorphism."
Being conjugated by a holomorphic automorphism means that $f$ and $g$ are really "the same". Therefore, this type of results means that there are no non-trivial way to deform the dynamics of $f$, hence that $f$ is "rigid".
Example of a non-rigid situation: if $f$ is say a polynomial map with an attracting fixed point whose multiplier is non-zero, it can be proved that you can conjugate $f$ to other polynomial maps $g$ with a different multiplier. This cannot be done with a holomorphic conjugacy, which must preserve multipliers; therefore $f$ is non-rigid.
Example of a rigid situation: take $f(z)=z^d$. It has two critical points, $0$ and $\infty$, which are fixed and have local degree $d$. These properties must be preserved by topological conjugacy, so if $g$ is topologically conjugated to $f$, then it must also have 2 fixed critical points with local degree $d$. You can assume without loss of generality that they are located at $0$ and $\infty$. Then it is not difficult to see that $g(z)=z^d$, hence $f$ is rigid.
